# How do you say 'I hope you got to know a little more about me'

Tags: expressions

For a self introduction speech in my chinese class.

P.s. please make it in "easy wording" with pinyin, thank you in advance. (not too complication)

Comment: 希望各位现在多一点认识我了 / Xīwàng gèwèi xiànzài duō yīdiǎn rènshi wǒ le

Answer (score 2):

希望 (hope) 你们 (you) 对我 (to me) 有了 (have) 更多的 (more) 了解 (understanding)

xī wàng nǐ men duì wǒ yǒu le gèng duō de liǎo jiě

Comment: `le` should be `è` or `e` ?

Comment: should be the latter

Answer (score 0):

The sentence can be translated as:

```
我希望你(们)可以多了解我一些
```

Comment: The OP needs some basic help here, just answering in Chinese is not enough.